# I want to know, how to log-in under my name?

Tags: support

I enter this site at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/. Usually I somehow get here under my own name and to my account. I am never asked for any log-in or password (why, by the way?)

However

1. I cannot get to my account from any other computer, and I use several of them. I simply do not see any place to enter my password.
2. Several times all of a sudden I was logged in differently. That is, under my name, but at another account. Again, I see no possibility to switch this one off and to log-in at my own account.

All that is extremely boring.

I would like to know:
1) Where is the log-in place, so that I can do it regularly under my own name to my own account.
Could it be done visible?

2) Where lies the description of how and where to log-in?

3) Where is the address of people who carry any responsibility about this site, just to ask for a support?

My e-mail adress: alexei.boulbitch@iee.lu. Answer me there, since I do not know where I will be logged-in the next time

Comment: Please see my answer to this question: [When I log in: what username must I use](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1199)

Comment: Alexei I tried help in answer to [your earlier question.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1223/121) (Which I have now merged into this one.)  Since apparently you did not find that useful I think you will need to contact the developers; from the [Contact us](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) page: team@stackexchange.com

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard It may well be that your answer is helpful. The problem is that I do not know, how to apply your advice. I never used Yahoo!, WordPress, Facebook and  MyOpenID, and before this day I only used Google for a search. So, if possible, please give me more detailed directions.

Comment: Alexei, you did create an openID for the other account. As @Mr.Wizard has said below you need to use the same openID to log in to that account (see my answer for a visual clue on where to login/choose the openID provider). Unfortunately, we cannot disclose what that openID is or the email associated with that account because we (the moderators) cannot verify your identity. Since there are some privacy issues and complexities involved, I strongly suggest directly emailing the SE team as they're better equipped to deal with such issues.

Comment: @ rm -rf Thank you. I now understand better what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Alexei, I'm sorry you're having trouble with this.  I am not sure of the problem, but I'll try to help as I am able.

Stack Exchange uses a system where you have one or more "Open ID" authentication methods attached to your account.  These are systems such as Yahoo!, WordPress, Facebook, MyOpenID, and Google.  Stack Exchange also has its own Open ID system now, so you don't need one of those other ones.  You must first log in to one of these Open ID systems before Mathematica.StackExchange.com will recognize you.

It looks like this account that you just created is using the Stack Exchange Open ID, while your main account is using something else.  It is also linked to a different email address.

Comment: Wizard Thank you for the answer. Explain please, where to read of how to make this OpenID and to use it? Could you please kindly answer me to the e-mail address alexei.boulbitch@iee.lu, since I do not know "what" I will be logged-in as tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, the StackExchange team seems to have solved my problem.